# Why is it that html 5 audio tag doesn't work on FF?

Tags: firefox, mp3, html5-audio, ogg

I've build an web application which plays some songs by using the html5 audio  tag. When I'm using FF(firefox) I have to play `ogg` files, and on IE I have to play `mp3` files.

The problem is that i just moved my webapp on godaddy servers, and the FF doesn't play the sounds anymore. On localhost FF play the sounds, but not on godaddy. Chrome plays the sounds on localhost as on godaddy.

This is the code I've use:

```
<audio id="ff01" src="/files/hello.ogg"></audio>
<audio id="ie01" src="/files/hello.mp3"></audio>
<button class="btn" onClick="document.getElementById('ff01').play()">FF</button>
<button class="btn" onClick="document.getElementById('ie01').play()">IE</button>
```

Can you tell me why the Firefox plays the files on `localhost`, but not on `godaddy`?

Comment: What `Content-Type` header does your server send for the .ogg file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by adding the following in the `.htaccess` file

```
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
```

Comment: For `.wav` files, add `AddType audio/x-ms-wma .wma` (thanks to [Configuring MIME Types in .htaccess](http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/gen/Configuring+MIME+Types+in+.htaccess))

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the mime type and place each audio file as children of the `audio` tag; try this:

```
<audio id="01">
  <source src="/files/hello.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="/files/hello.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: ty for the answer. I use that format now, but it didn't solve the problem.